# Docker local private registry in minikube using the docker driver

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, minikube, docker-registry

### Question

How to run a local Docker private registry in minikube while using the docker driver? (`--driver=docker`)

### The issue

**Connection refused** when pushing images to private registry

```sh
docker push docker-registry.kubemaster.me/docker-cats:latest

# Results
The push refers to repository [docker-registry.kubemaster.me/docker-cats]
Get http://docker-registry.kubemaster.me/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

### My Setup

Minikube on Windows WSL2 using [minikube's docker driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/).

```sh
minikube start --driver=docker --kubernetes-version=v1.20.2
```

I've deployed [nginx-ingress-controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) which listens on ports 80 and 443. The application is available via both HTTP and HTTPS (using [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) for TLS certificates). And of course, I added `127.0.0.1 docker-registry.kubemaster.me` to my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

**NOTE**: I'm running `minikube tunnel` in the background, this is why it's possible to communicate with the whole cluster from the host via nginx-ingress-controller.

### Accessing the local registry

- From the **Windows Host**

  [image: access-from-windows-host]
- From the **WSL2 Ubuntu** guest machine.

  ```sh
  curl  http://docker-registry.kubemaster.me/v2/_catalog
  ```

  [image: access-from-ubuntu-guest]
- From **minikube's docker container**

  ```sh
  docker exec -it minikube bash
  root@minikube:/$ curl  http://docker-registry.kubemaster.me/v2/_catalog
  ```

  [image: access-from-minikube-container]
- Pushing from **minikube's docker container**

  ```sh
  docker exec -it minikube bash
  root@minikube:/$ docker push docker-registry.kubemaster.me/docker-cats
  Using default tag: latest
  The push refers to repository [docker-registry.kubemaster.me/docker-cats]
  346be19f13b0: Layer already exists 
  935f303ebf75: Layer already exists 
  0e64bafdc7ee: Pushed 
  latest: digest: 
  sha256:5403064f94b617f7975a19ba4d1a1299fd584397f6ee4393d0e16744ed11aab1 size: 943
  ```

### YAML - Deployment, Service and Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: docker-registry
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: docker-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: docker-registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: registry:2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: docker-registry
          env:
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET
              value: "some-secret"
            - name: REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR
              value: "0.0.0.0:80"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              hostPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 400Mi
              cpu: "200m"
            requests:
              memory: 200Mi
              cpu: 100m
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: docker-registry
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    k8s-app: docker-registry
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 2000m # support large images
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: docker-registry.kubemaster.me
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              serviceName: docker-registry
              servicePort: 80
```

P.S- My setup of how to deploy a local Kubernetes cluster for development purposes - https://github.com/unfor19/kubernetes-localdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropped this idea, instead, I'm using minikube's Docker daemon by executing

```sh
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```